# Get ID of a row having an other value on form Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

How can I get the id value having the name value?

I have this form:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="projectclientexist" name="projectclientexist">
    @foreach ($clients as $key => $client)
    <div class="radio">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label><input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->name}}">{{$client->name}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" value="Crear relacion Proyecto-Cliente" id="relationclientexist" name="relationclientexist" class="btn btn-success">
</form>
```

How can I do it to take the id value of the client having the name value?

```
public function storeProjectsClientsIfExist (Request $request)
{
    $client_project->project = new Client_Project();

    $client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')
                                ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(id) "));

    $client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')
                                ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from projects)"))
                                ->first()
                                ->id;
    $client_project->save();
}
```

Thanks a lot, if have any question about the code, you can ask it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question ?

Comment: Of course;) How to get the id of the client, when you pass the name value on form;)

Comment: Try this `$client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('name', $request('client'))->first()->id;` :)
            `

Comment: Know why when i submit go to: http://web.loc/admin/projects?client=projecto+de+prueba&relationclientexist=Crear+relacion+Proyecto-Cliente ? Maybe some id it's wrong, i think

Comment: Because you didn't add the route to hit after submiting in the form nor the method.

Comment: This problem is solved, i put a wrong #id in ajax. Anyway, when i submit and check logs. `Creating default object from empty value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can try this :

```
public function storeProjectsClientsIfExist(Request $request)
       {
            $client_project->project = new Client_Project();
            $client_project->client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('name', $request->client)->first()->id;
            $client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from projects)"))->first()->id;
            $client_project->save();
        }
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 2):

Weirdly asked. If I correctly understand your questino, you want to get the ID of the chosen client?

If that's the case, in view, `value` attributes of fields have to store the ID:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->name}}</label>
```

Then, in the controller, you get the checked client like this:

```
$clientID = $request->input('client'); // or $request->client;
$clientObj = Client::find($clientID); // Your client model object, if needed. Equals to: DB::table('clients')->find($clientID);
```

**EDIT:** I think your `Creating default object from empty value` error happens because you try to add a property on an non-object in `$client_project->project = new Client_Project();`. You have to define `$client_project` as an object with `stdClass` (it is a default class, with no property, no method. A bit like a empty javascript object).

So here we are:

```
public function storeProjectsClientsIfExist (Request $request)
{
    $clientID = $request->input('name'); // get the name field value.

    $client_project = new \stdClass(); // define the var as an object.

    $client_project->project = new Client_Project();
    $client_project->client_id = $clientID;
    // currently the next line get the last project added in DB
    $client_project->project_id = DB::table('projects')
        ->where('id', DB::raw("(select max(`id`) from projects)"))
        ->first()
        ->id;

    // I think "$client_project->save();" will not work
    $client_project->project->save();

    return view('my.view'); // or redirect()->route('my.route') or what you want
}
```

Comment: Hi, that's a good and easier idea. Anyway, give me an error: `Creating default object from empty value`

Comment: The `$clientObj` part of my answer works if a `Client` model has been defined. In your case, I think you can just use `$clientID` for your `$client_project->client_id`.

Comment: Did you "call" your model with `Use App\Client;` before your controller class definition?

Comment: Yes @iArcadia, its declared with `use App\Models\Client;`

Comment: I have one error in syntax, let me remake the code and i will post if works or not:D

Comment: Well, i just fixed with `$client_project->client_id = $request->client;` if you want, you can edit your answer and put all the function of the controller, and if work, i will mark it as correct:D

Comment: Are you talking about this `Creating default object from empty value` error? :p Isn't your problem already resolved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151068/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-iarcadia).

Answer (score 1):

If you want selected client's you have to pass id of client in value instead of name

```
@foreach ($clients as $key => $client)
          <div class="radio">
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="client" value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->name}}</label>
                  </div>
          </div>
      @endforeach
```

Comment: I try it like you say, and then in controller do this?: `$client_project->client_id = $request->input("client");` give me an error: `Creating default object from empty value` . I like the idea of passing on value the client id, easy way to take the value on controller. Know how to fix the error?

Comment: Will you try `$client_project->client_id = $request->client;` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you have only id associated with name then try this:

```
$client_id = DB::table('clients')->where('name',$request->client))->first()->id;
```

If many id associated with given name then you can use this:

```
$client_ids = DB::table('clients')->where('name',$request->client))->pluck('id');
```